# How to make a table in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to make a simple table in Matlab, so I used this code:

```
T := table(a = 13, c = 42)
```

But it gives an error:

> xrd
>   Undefined function 'T' for input arguments of type
>   'char'.
>   Error in xrd (line 1)
>   T := table(a = 13, c = 42)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by table? An array? a uitable?

Comment: an array is enough but if you may, please provide a syntax for uitable

Comment: Please read about basic programming concepts in documentation. try `doc uitable`

Comment: You should also define what output you expect. Draw the table or something to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 4):

`:=` is no operator in Matlab, this screws up interpreting your line of code. Matlab tries to access a function named T with the rest of the line as string argument.

Try

```
a = 13
b = 42    
t = table(a, b)
```

Output:

```
t = 

    a     b 
    __    __

    13    42
```

For rownames you can use:

```
>>t = table(a, b, 'RowNames', {'c'})

t = 

         a     b 
         __    __

    c    13    42
```

note that RowNames argument is a cell with a string for each row

Comment: how but to put a header above those numbers? like a=13, and b=42?

Comment: Although this command does not generate errors, the output is `t =  1`. Are you sure that is the correct output (the OP should define the output)? Looking at the documentation for [table](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), I would expect one row and two columns.

Comment: what do you mean by header? the colums are named after the variables which they represent (a and b in this case), for naming the rows you can use the RowNames argument/value pair

Answer (score 1):

In matlab, `table` has a specific meaning (see [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?refresh=true)) which is probably different from what you are used to in other langages.

For what you are trying to do, maybe you should consider to define a structure instead:

```
T = struct('a', 13, 'c', 42)
```

Check the `struct` documentation for more detail:

```
doc struct
```

Answer (score 0):

As the MATLAB way to initialize a table with predefined column names seems particularly obscure to me, I am documenting it here.

Be aware that I use the `cell2table` function once to initialize the table.
From then on, `jobTable.FOO = ...;` will enable you to create further columns `FOO`.

```
jobTable = cell2table([{'running'}, {'queued'}, {'finished'}]', 'VariableNames', {'state'});
jobTable.rank = [0, 1, -1]';
jobTable.workflowId = [0, 29039, 28000]';
```

You can transform the table into a struct, which is e.g. more useful for communication with java, by using: `table2struct(jobTable)`.